# Unable to run SELECT INTO OUTFILE on Google MySQL and cannot Grant File to user root. Access denied

Tags: mysql, gcloud

I have a Google MySQL database and I can login from my local MySQL workbench. I need to export the data from it using command `SELECT... INTO OUTFILE`.

I have tried this:

```
grant all privileges 
  on mydatabase.* 
  to 'root'@'%' 
  identified by 'mypassword';
flush privileges;
```

which works, but when I next ran this:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' identified by 'mypassword';
```

I got this error and still cannot SELECT INTO OUTFILE

> Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password:
>   YES)

Further check:

- `show user()` gives me `root@[my PC's IP address]`
- `show current_user()` gives me `root@'%'`

Please advise how I can run SELECT INTO OUTFILE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv), exporting in CSV format is equivalent to run SELECT... INTO OUTFILE query.

On the other hand, in case you want to do it locally, once you are connected to the DB, as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#before_you_begin_2), you can use the  "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" statement in mysql client to loads a local file to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I run the export from the console. I see this prompt `You will not be able to perform operations on your instance for the entire duration of the export`. Will my other applications still be able to read and write to the database when the export is in progress?

Comment: Operation refers to operations on the control plane (e.g. changing the settings of the DB). You can use the DB instance as usual (read/write) during the exporting data